# How to equate coefficients of two quadratic equations to find the unknowns

Tags: matlab

I have these equations, `e1=S^2-k2*s-k1` and `e2=s^2+0.7*s+0.12` and `e1=e2`
now, by the naked eye you can see, `k1=-0.12` and `k2=-0.7`. But I need a matlab code to evaluate this. Please help.
Thank You

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
% Define your functions
f1 =@(s, k) s.^2 - k(2).*s - k(1)
f2 =@(s) s.^2 + 0.7*s + 0.12

% Define your initial guess
k0 = rand(2,1);

% Make sure you have enough equations
SMin = -5;
SMax = 5;
NEqn = 10 * length(k0)
S = (SMax - SMin) * rand(NEqn , 1) + SMin;

% find the coefficients
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','none','MaxFunctionEvaluations', 10000, 'TolPCG', 1E-10, 'TolFun', 1E-10);
x = fsolve(@(k) f1(S, k) - f2(S), k0 )
```

Comment: There's a little bit of parameter fiddling for nonlinear problems